# Not able to push images to openshift registry

Tags: docker, kubernetes, openshift, redhat, docker-registry

I have installed openshift (Master and Slave).

```
oc version
oc v3.7.23
kubernetes v1.7.6+a08f5eeb62
features: Basic-Auth GSSAPI Kerberos SPNEGO

Server https://cbc-rh-os-m01.com:8443
openshift v3.7.23
kubernetes v1.7.6+a08f5eeb62
```

and I have persistent volume (Netapp Trident) mapped to the openshift registry.

and when I try to deploy image into the registry it give this

```
[root@cbc-rh-os-m01 ~]# docker push 172.30.84.81:5000/default/hello-world:v1
The push refers to a repository [172.30.84.81:5000/default/hello-world]
f999ae22f308: Retrying in 1 second
received unexpected HTTP status: 500 Internal Server Error
```

and when I looked for the logs internally, I find this.

```
time="2018-03-12T14:44:59.500127756Z" level=debug msg="filesystem.PutContent(\"/docker/registry/v2/repositories/default/hello-world/_uploads/92e5122e-ae51-43c3-a76d-b52b63da2012/startedat\")" go.version=go1.8.3 http.request.host="172.30.84.81:5000" http.request.id=01806345-1d84-43d4-abe3-9a57e44c9dd7 http.request.method=POST http.request.remoteaddr="10.128.0.1:52916" http.request.uri="/v2/default/hello-world/blobs/uploads/" http.request.useragent="docker/1.12.6 go/go1.8.3 kernel/3.10.0-693.21.1.el7.x86_64 os/linux arch/amd64 UpstreamClient(Docker-Client/1.12.6 \\(linux\\))" instance.id=163e0994-bfa3-4647-830b-a7ac9d51f92f openshift.auth.user=admin openshift.auth.userid=a93b53f4-2384-11e8-9e3a-0050569261d7 openshift.logger=registry trace.duration=118.164µs trace.file="/builddir/build/BUILD/atomic-openshift-git-0.8edc154/_output/local/go/src/github.com/openshift/origin/vendor/github.com/docker/distribution/registry/storage/driver/base/base.go" trace.func="github.com/openshift/origin/vendor/github.com/docker/distribution/registry/storage/driver/base.(*Base).PutContent" trace.id=4c482511-bbcd-4a7b-a80d-5d563ec64e60 trace.line=95 vars.name="default/hello-world"
time="2018-03-12T14:44:59.500412514Z" level=error msg="response completed with error" err.code=unknown err.detail="filesystem: mkdir /registry/docker: permission denied" err.message="unknown error" go.version=go1.8.3 http.request.host="172.30.84.81:5000" http.request.id=01806345-1d84-43d4-abe3-9a57e44c9dd7 http.request.method=POST http.request.remoteaddr="10.128.0.1:52916" http.request.uri="/v2/default/hello-world/blobs/uploads/" http.request.useragent="docker/1.12.6 go/go1.8.3 kernel/3.10.0-693.21.1.el7.x86_64 os/linux arch/amd64 UpstreamClient(Docker-Client/1.12.6 \\(linux\\))" http.response.contenttype="application/json; charset=utf-8" http.response.duration=11.001444ms http.response.status=500 http.response.written=156 instance.id=163e0994-bfa3-4647-830b-a7ac9d51f92f openshift.auth.user=admin openshift.auth.userid=a93b53f4-2384-11e8-9e3a-0050569261d7 openshift.logger=registry vars.name="default/hello-world"
10.128.0.1 - - [12/Mar/2018:14:44:59 +0000] "POST /v2/default/hello-world/blobs/uploads/ HTTP/1.1" 500 156 "" "docker/1.12.6 go/go1.8.3 kernel/3.10.0-693.21.1.el7.x86_64 os/linux arch/amd64 UpstreamClient(Docker-Client/1.12.6 \\(linux\\))"
```

Comment: This seems to be a permissions issue: `err.detail="filesystem: mkdir /registry/docker: permission denied" `

Comment: I figured out that too, but when I reverted back to the original volume it was attached too, then also it throws similar error.

Comment: It might be blocked by Selinux.

Comment: @ccshih https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.7/install_config/install/prerequisites.html#prereq-selinux      Pre-requisite ask to keep it enabled

Answer (score 0):

Create the binary in openshift:

```
oc new-build --name=hello-world --binary=true
```

cd to the directory where the `Dockerfile` lives.

```
oc start-build hello-world --from-dir=hello-world --follow
```